# Keras Multiclass Clasification input_shape size problem

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, categorical-data

I am building a face detection AI using Keras. I have collected the data in the following form:

dataset
  - a
  - b
  - c
  - d
main.py

In this, a,b,c, and d are the classes each containing images. I want to use the image_dataset_from_directory command but when I try to resize all the images to 400x400, it throws telling me that the shapes 160000 and 400x400 are incompatible. But if I resize to images to 1,160000, everything works but has bad accuracy due to the distorted image. Any help is appreciated.

I am using python 3.7 with tensorflow 2.3 and tf-nightly

Here is the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 400, 400) for input Tensor("flatten_input:0", shape=(None, 400, 400), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (400, 400, 1).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\mainm.py", line 48, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict_on_batch(pred[1][0])
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1766, in predict_on_batch
    outputs = predict_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2841, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3199, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3061, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 979, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 966, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1440 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1430 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1063 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2377 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2736 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1423 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1396 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:961 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:372 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:385 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:507 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:952 __call__
        self.name)
    C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\custom face\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 160000 but received input with shape [400, 400]
```

And here is my code:

```
from libraries import *

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))


data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("dataset", labels="inferred", label_mode="categorical",class_names=['a','b','c','d'], color_mode='grayscale', image_size=(400,400), )

labels = ['k','am','ash','an']

model = keras.Sequential([ #sequential says to list layers in sequence
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(400,400)), #Input layer setup. making data from [[1],[2],[3]] to [1,2,3]
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"), #1st hidden layer of 128 neurons, Dense means all layers interconnected equally. Activation is the rectifier linear
    # unit making the proccesing complex. It does this by making all negetives 0 and all positives bigger.
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")#softmaxout layer of 10 neurons, activation gives a probability for each of the 10 output choices
])

# Compile up

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])# loss function is where you look at the probability and

# change weights and biases based on how much you lost. metric is what you want to achieve.

#Train
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

#model.fit(data,epochs=1, callbacks = [cp_callback]) #epochs are how many times the network sees the same data during training. feeds data randomly. gives

model.load_weights("training_1/cp.ckpt")

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(data)
print("Tested Loss: ", test_loss)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc*100, "%")

unbatched = data.unbatch()
print("================")
pred = list(unbatched.as_numpy_iterator())
print(len(pred))
prediction = model.predict_on_batch(pred[1][0])
# img = Image.fromarray(pred[0][0], 'RGB')
# img.save('my.png')
# img.show()
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Programming issues are off-topic here. Please, read https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. So, I will migrate this post to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keras.layers.Flatten(...

You can't start the model with this layer, it only accepts vectors.
Use Conv2D and then the next layers. It's best if you see more examples of working models. This will allow you to get better results and make fewer mistakes.

example:
https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/

Comment: I am not sure what the filter and kernel_size are. I tried some commonly used values and it gives me this error:

Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [400, 400, 1]

Comment: There is probably a mistake in the shape of the data you enter. min_ndim = 4 means there must be 4 values ​​and most likely it is: (number of photos, img_rows, img_cols, channnels). Write where exactly this error occurs.

Comment: I managed to fix that error by making the line to:

keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(1,1),input_shape=(None,400,400,1)),

but now it gives me an error on the output layer by saying:

ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 400, 400, 1, 4) are incompatible

Comment: You probably need to use an intermediate layer before this last layer to get rid of this error. Try this:
......
model.add(Conv2D(.....))

**model.add(Flatten())**

model.add(Dense(....)) # last layer

Comment: I added a flatten right after the conv2d and it gives me this:

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

I belive it is pointing to the conv2d where I set my dimensions to None,400,400,1. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Also if I set the None bach_size (or the first number in the input_shape) it crashes my laptop and I have to hard reboot it. 

Laptop specs:
16G ram
Core i5
No individual graphics card

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I solved it in the end by tweaking the numbers!

Comment: I didn't get a notification, that's why I write back so late. I'm glad everything is working now. When it comes to computing power, I recommend using https://colab.research.google.com, you can set GPU support and performance is enormously higher compared to a middle-class PC